# How to make QML object visible before some "heavy" operation in C++ code

Tags: qt, qml, qfile

I've got the following logic in QML:

```
button click handler in QML:

1) rectangle.visible=true

2) call some C++ method
```

in C++ method, i call QFile::copy, which copies files from USB storage, and prints logs to rectangle above(which must be already visible). But as i understand, QML makes element visible only after button click handler executed, but QFile::copy is too slow, so i see logs(rectangle become visible) only after all files were copied. So my question is, how to make rectangle which contains logs visible(really "visible") before QFile::copy was called. Of course i can implement async copy, but i'm novice in Qt, so may be there is some solution.

Thank you

Comment: I advice you to run heavy tasks in a different thread, either [WorkerScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-workerscript.html)(QML) or QThread (C++) so the GUI thread will not be blocked.

Comment: connect your message logging signals in `main.cpp` to your `window` (root object of the engine context) so whenever there's a new text emitted, you can add it to your `rectangle`. Also take into consideration the above comment (create a c++ class in your main and use `moveToThread` so you can decouple it from the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your big task in a `QThread`:

thetask.hpp

```
#ifndef THETASK_HPP
#define THETASK_HPP

#include <QThread>

class TheTask: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        TheTask(/* Put operation args here, or through some setters. */);

    protected:
        void run() override;

        // Put stuff for storing operation's arguments and results here.
};

#endif  // THETASK_HPP
```

thetask.cpp

```
#include "thetask.hpp"

TheTask::TheTask() :
    QThread()
    // Init stuff for storing operation's arguments and results.
{}

void TheTask::run() {
    // Put your heavy C++ operation here
}
```

heavy.hpp

```
#ifndef HEAVY_HPP
#define HEAVY_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
class TheTask;

class Heavy: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Heavy();
        virtual ~Heavy();

        /// @brief QML registration
        static void declareQML();

        /// @brief Your heavy operation
        Q_INVOKABLE void doTheBigOperation(/* Operation args */);

    protected:
        /// @brief Storing the running threads for objects lifecycle reasons.
        /// 
        /// The bigOp object would be destroyed at the end of the
        /// Heavy::doTheBigOperation() method. In order to keep it alive,
        /// let's store it in a list.
        QList<TheTask *> bigOps;

    signals:
        /// @brief Emitted when everything is finished.
        void afterBigOp(/* Put operation results here */);

    protected slots:
        /// @brief Treatments to do when the operation is finished.
        void bigOpFinished();
};

#endif  // HEAVY_HPP
```

heavy.cpp

```
#include "anchor.hpp"
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include "thetask.hpp"

Heavy::Heavy() :
    QObject(),
    bigOps()
{}

Heavy::~Heavy() {
    // Delete threads pointers properly.
    while (!bigOps.isEmpty()) {
        TheTask * thread = bigOps.takeLast();

        // Stopping threads. Be careful on consequences.
        thread->quit();
        thread->wait();

        thread->deleteLater();
    }
}

void Heavy::declareQML() {
    qmlRegisterType<Heavy>("CppGates", 13, 37, "Heavy");
}

void Heavy::doTheBigOperation(/* Operation args */) {
    TheTask * bigOp = new TheTask(/* Operation args */);

    // A thread emits the QThread::finised() signal when its task is finished.
    connect(bigOp, &TheTask::finished,
            this,  &Heavy::bigOpFinished);

    // Keeping the thread alive (cf. bigOps documentation).
    bigOps << bigOp;

    // Start executing the heavy operation.
    bigOp->start();
}

void Heavy::bigOpFinished() {
    // Retrieving the thread, which is the signal sender.
    TheTask * thread = qobject_cast<TheTask *>(sender());

    // The treatment is over: let's broke communication with its thread.
    disconnect(thread, &TheTask::finished,
               this,   &Heavy::bigOpFinished);

    // Extract operation results from the thread.

    // Removing the thread from the running threads list.
    int threadIndex = bigOps.indexOf(thread);
    bigOps.removeAt(threadIndex);

    thread->deleteLater();

    // Telling QML that the heavy operation is over.
    emit afterBigOp(/* Operation results */);
}
```

RectComp.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import CppGates 13.37

Item {
    id: qml_comp

    Heavy { id: controller }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle

        // ...
    }

    function doItHeavy() {
        rectangle.visible = false
        controller.doTheBigOperation(/* Operation arguments */)
    }

    function afterTheBigOp(/* Operation results */) {
        // Put here things you would like to do after controller.doTheBigOperation()
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Connecting a callback to the signal emitted after the heavy operation.
        controller.afterBigOp.connect(qml_comp.afterTheBigOp)
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "heavy.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv() {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // ...

    Heavy::declareQML();

    // ...

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    int res = engine.rootObjects().isEmpty() ? -1 : app.exec();

    // ...

    return res;
}
```

For further information, please have a look at `QThread`'s reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Answer (score 0):

One possible "simple" solution that does not involve using threads, is to delay calling your c++ method using qml timers:

button click handler in QML:

1. rectangle.visible=true
2. call timer with delay "d"
3. after "d" the timer will trigger and call your C++ method (by then,
   the rectangle should have become visible

Code:

```
Rectangle {
   id: rectangle
}
Button {
   onClicked: {
      rectangle.visible = true
      timer.start()
   }
}
Timer {
   id: timer
   interval: 100
   onTriggered: myCppMethod()
}
```

Please note, that this does not prevent your application from becoming unresponsive for the duration of the c++ method execution. A better way is to move your cpp method to another thread and call it from the main thread using signals and slots.